# Replace Html.CheckBoxFor with Bootstrap Toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

As of now im using `@Html.CheckBoxFor` and would like to replace that with a Bootstrap Toggle.

I have tried this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsEnded, new { id = "toggle-switch", data_toggle = "toggle", data_size = "small", data_on = "On", data_off = "Off" })
```

This is not working. I see the toggle and can set it to on/off, but i can not bind the model data to the toggle!

Any ideas? :)

**UPDATE:**

Deleted the bootstrap-toggle.js from Scripts folder and bootstrap-toggle.css from Content folder and added reference in the view:

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

and removed the references in BundleConfig

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Now i works like a charm!

But i would really like **NOT** to add references in the view and keep it to bundles, so does anyone have an idea, why it´s not working when included in bundles?